# angular 7 + angular cli 7+ ng test not working

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, angular7, angular-cli-v7

angular 7 + angular cli 7.1.0

upgraded project from angular 5 to 7 
and when run 
    `ng test`

and `tsConfig` added in `angular.json` file

```
` "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "test.js",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "apps/app/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",`
```

I get the output 
 `Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" should have required property 'tsConfig'.`

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your path of the tsConfig is wrong.
Change it to

```
"tsConfig": "apps/app/src/tsconfig.spec.json"
```

Answer (score 1):

In my angular 7 project ng test is working. below is my agular.json file test configuration.

```
   "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "src/test.ts",
        "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
        "scripts": [
          "src/assets/jquery-3.2.1.min.js",
          "src/assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css",
        ],
        "assets": [
          "src/assets",
          "src/favicon.ico"
        ]
      }
    },
```